# Unexpected behaviour of Javascript form

Tags: javascript, html

When I click on the "click me" button after entering the value as 22 I don't see any changes on the web page. How can I fix this?

```js
function fun() {
  n = document.getElementById("number").value;
  headingTag = document.getElementById("h2");
  headingTag.innerText = n;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="number">
  <button onclick="fun()">Click Me!</button>
</form>
<h2 id="h2"></h2>
```

Comment: Code works, but you forgot to `preventDefault`, so the page gets replaced

Comment: Can you please modify the code. I am new to this stuff.

Comment: See the canonical

Comment: what is canonical?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is because, the default *type* of button is *submit*. Thus when clicking, the submission of the form is taking place. You can either use [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to prevent the event or specify `type="button"` in the button:

```html
<body>
   <form>
       <input type="text" id="number">
       <button onclick="fun(event)">Click Me!</button>
   </form> 
   <h2 id="h2"></h2>
   <script>
       function fun(e){
         n = document.getElementById("number").value;
         headingTag = document.getElementById("h2");
         headingTag.innerText = n;
         e.preventDefault();
       }
   </script>
</body>
```

By changing the type:

```html
<body>
   <form>
       <input type="text" id="number">
       <button type="button" onclick="fun()">Click Me!</button>
   </form> 
   <h2 id="h2"></h2>
   <script>
       function fun(){
         n = document.getElementById("number").value;
         headingTag = document.getElementById("h2");
         headingTag.innerText = n;
       }
   </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `preventDefault()` to stop the form submit behaviour by the button. [Refer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

```js
function fun(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  n = document.getElementById("number").value;
  headingTag = document.getElementById("h2");
  headingTag.innerText = n;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="number">
    <button onclick="fun(event)">Click Me!</button>
  </form>
  <h2 id="h2"></h2>
</body>
```